# I am unable to edit my shortcuts on Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to add in my jupyter notebook a shortcut for runnning all the cells, i thought that might be useful for running big notebooks at once, I am actually new on Jupyter Notebook editor and when i try to add this shortcut on " Help > Edit Keyboard Shortcut " I get nothing on the upcoming page.

[image: my ss for edit keyboard shortcut part]

I googled this issue and saw some solutions like updating jupyter notebook to the latest version, but I have tried it already and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found a few references to this being fixed by downgrading Jupyter rather than upgrading it.

You could do this by forcing it to install to a previous version :

```
pip install jupyter==5.0.0
```

Comment: I tried that too, i get an another Invalid Operator Error, I tried it with == too and then got No matching distribution found for jupyter==5.0.0. But thanks in advance!

Comment: [link](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html) This webpage will show you all the versions of Jupyter. Maybe try the one that comes just before the one you have installed.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work. Nevertheless thank you so much for helping me out!